# Linking to shops product page

Tags: discussion

I just saw a post which suggests a few books, each suggestion has a link to the page on Amazon.

I assume by the URL that this allows tracking by the shop. The link is  http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0130183806 and if you click it you are taken to Amazon.

So, my question is if I link to Amazon or a bookshop/computershop etc, is there a protocol to follow to show that the link originated at stackoverflow?

Dave

Comment: the URLs to Amazon books are automatically rewritten to include [se]'s referral links [Auto-Inserting Stack Overflow affiliate into all Amazon book links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/26964)

Comment: Ah, thank you for the update. Does this mean there is a preference to what sites we link to (eg bookstore1.com or bookstore2.com etc)

Answer (score 1):

> So, my question is if I link to Amazon or a bookshop/computershop etc, is there a protocol to follow to show that the link originated at stackoverflow?

Strictly speaking there's no protocol -

- All links to Amazon books are rewritten to include Stack Exchange's affiliate URL
- I'm not aware of other URLs that get rewritten
- You can opt to link to any site - though including your own referral link is likely to result in your post being flagged for spam